# DB upload in mysql - loses UTF characters

Tags: sql, database, mysql, remote-access

I'm frequently updating my db on the server, and I run the following line from the command line:

```
mysqldump -u root --password=mypass mydb|mysql -h mysite.cc -u remotusr --password=remotpsw remotdb
```

The problem is that it loses the UTF characters along the way.

How can I keep the utf chars in cmd, or what is a better practice doing this?

Comment: So instead of unicode chars I get '?'

Comment: That version of mysqldump should, by default, include a `SET NAMES` command and output UTF-8. Perhaps an option file is overriding this behaviour?  Try `--no-defaults` to ignore option files.  Failing that, can you use `--result-file=file` to save the dump output and then inspect it to see whether it contains the problem; then, if not, use mysql to connect to the target machine and run that saved script using [`source`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/batch-commands.html)?  If both of those succeed, the problem must be in your command shell.  If one of them fails, please let us know which.

Comment: The problem is that both dbs are now utf8, both show correct records in mysql_admin, but on the site, instead of '⇨' character it shows '?'.

Comment: So the data imported into the new database correctly?  It sounds like the problem must lie in how you are retrieving and displaying it, which you do not disclose in your question.

Comment: Well I simply use `mysql_query('select name from top_menu where....')` the funny thing, is when I submit this data on the site, it would show normally, but if I dump the db from my another site - no way. Even though in both cases it displays just fine in the php_myadmin.

Comment: What language is that? PHP? Have you specified the connection character set with `mysql_set_charset()`? Also, as stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: I haven't tried `mysql_set_charset()` yet, just going to try it know. I know the mysql_ is outdated though, but I wonder if it might be the reason.

Comment: Damn, you are genious :) mysql_set_charset('utf8'); did the trick. thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*( Upgrading to an answer )*

As documented under [*`mysqldump`* — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html):

> - [`--default-character-set=charset_name`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_default-character-set)
>
>   Use ***`charset_name`*** as the default character set. See [Section 10.5, “Character Set Configuration”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-configuration.html). If no character set is specified, [*`mysqldump`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) uses `utf8`, and earlier versions use `latin1`.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - [`--set-charset`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-charset)
>
>   Add `SET NAMES default_character_set` to the output. This option is enabled by default. To suppress the **`SET NAMES`** statement, use [`--skip-set-charset`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-charset).

Therefore, unless you have settings in an option file which are overriding these defaults (you can specify [`--no-defaults`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_no-defaults) to ensure they are not), the output from *`mysqldump`* should be more than capable of being redirected to another *`mysql`* session without loss of Unicode characters.

Instead, the conversion to a smaller character set appears to be occurring on retrieving & displaying your data from the new database.  Since you are using PHP's Original MySQL API for this purpose, despite the warning in [the introduction to its manual chapter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) (below), you should use [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to set the connection character set.

> This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.